# Rhythmbox stops playing radio

Tags: rhythmbox

The Rhythmbox plays radio hbr1.com for exact 4 minutes and stops and it says

`server does not support seeking`.

and then again when I click on button 'play' it starts again normal. I don't think that this is problem of network cause i got Jio network with 4G Internet which is pretty fast in my country.
[image]

#### NEW INFO

I had installed clean Ubuntu mate nearly 1-2 month ago.but since last 3 days i am encountering this problem again.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in `gstreamer` which is the core component of Rhythmbox that does the streaming. Gstreamer expects a "content length" header, but the station doesn't provide one. After the first buffer of radio data is played, Rhythmbox thinks the stream has finished. I couldn't actually find an open bug that matches this behaviour but it certainly sounds like one.

Comment: so is there any way to fix this bug??

Comment: You may be able to report this at bugzilla.gnome.org (if it is a duplicate they will tell you). In the meantime you could switch to [gradio](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/gradio-5-0-released-mpris-features) which is a nice radio app that keeps going on after 4 minutes (I tried).

Comment: please could you tell me that how can i report the bug in answer.

Comment: i am new to ubuntu

Comment: First, create an account; then, open a new bug with the description above, for the package `rhythmbox` and include 1) the exact name of the radio station, 2) the version of Rhythmbox you use (see Help), 3) the full version of Ubuntu that you use (try the command `uname -a`).

Comment: For an even more complete bug report, try the following: from a terminal enter `rhythmbox -d` and start your station. Watch the output of the terminal command. After four minutes, when the playback stops, copy the output and paste it into your bug report (they don't mind if your logging is very long).

Comment: nothing happened. problem is still occurring.

Comment: @voldemort I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you report the bug?

Comment: Although my problem is a little different (I don't get any error message) I opened a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791164).